# Drag and drop in long layouts

Tags: android, android-layout

I can't finish the design of my page. I have a relative layout inside a linear layout inside a scrollview. My relative layout has a max width of 800, the drag and drop feature can only see the size of the current device screen size you are using.

How can I view the area below it? I can't get this app done, I'm still getting around on how to use the android studio IDE. I've just been guessing the alignment manually through the xml file and I just wasted 4 hours.

This is just for aligning the elements properly. But I can't do it if I can't see it.

Comment: alignment? what alignment are you talking about?

Comment: @pskink hi, im talking about the positioning of the fields or elements of the layout (edittext, textview, imageview). relative layouts are dependent on each other for positioning andni need ro alihn some of them together. Sorry if im unclear

Comment: let me check if this is clear, your problem is that when dragging an item around, you can't scroll down the view ( which should be encapsulated inside a root view of type ScrollView, granting you the scroll ) ?

Comment: I did find a solution but i think there is still a better way to this, i just used a different device with a bigger screen for viewing just to see the whole page of the layout.

Comment: @francescoC Yes! Thank you for making my problem clearer

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView class holds some API to allow you to scroll based on a given offset.

If you can calculate when the touch event has reached the limit of your view ( I imagine it would be the bottom or top edge of your screen, but I guess it does not restrict to this ) you can tell your scrollView to scroll a bit. 
I've thrown out a few quick tests and found some troubles caused by event delegates (like, ScrollView touch event is bad handled and interrupted when the dragNDrop event handler of the views kicks in, or the other way around). Haven't tested this, but having a top level transparent clickthrough layout could help in some cases, but that's just an un-tested idea